# Combining Scala streams

Tags: scala, stream

I have the need to combine values from several (possibly infinite) streams, the number of streams may vary; sometimes to "draw one from each" and handle them as a tuple, sometimes to interleave the values.

Sample input could be like this:

```
val as= Stream.from(0)
val bs= Stream.from(10)
val cs= Stream.from(100)
val ds= Stream.from(1000)
val list= List(as, bs, cs, ds)
```

For the first use case, I would like to end up with something like

```
Seq(0, 10, 100, 1000), Seq(1, 11, 101, 1001), ...
```

and for the second

```
Seq(0, 10, 100, 1000, 1, 11, 101, 1001, ...
```

Is there a standard, or even built-in, solution for combining `Stream`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is identical to the solution from Eastsun but easier to understand:

```
def combine[A](s:Seq[Stream[A]]):Stream[Seq[A]]=s.map(_.head) #:: combine(s.map(_.tail))
```

Comment: Maybe `flatMap(_.headOption)` in case the streams are not infinite?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
scala> val coms = Stream.iterate(list)(_ map (_.tail)) map (_ map (_.head))
coms: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[List[Int]] = Stream(List(0, 10, 100, 1000), ?)

scala> coms take 5 foreach println
List(0, 10, 100, 1000)
List(1, 11, 101, 1001)
List(2, 12, 102, 1002)
List(3, 13, 103, 1003)
List(4, 14, 104, 1004)

scala> val flat = coms.flatten
flat: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> flat take 12 toList
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 10, 100, 1000, 1, 11, 101, 1001, 2, 12, 102, 1002)
```

Comment: That is much more succinct, indeed, though perhaps even less readable for the untrained eye...

Answer (score 0):

The best I have come up with yet looks a bit "crowded", as if I'm trying to write a textbook example of stream operations...

```
def combine[A](list: List[Stream[A]]): Stream[Seq[A]] = {
  val listOfSeqs= list.map(_.map(Seq(_))) // easier to reduce when everything are Seqs...
  listOfSeqs.reduceLeft((stream1, stream2)=> stream1 zip stream2 map {
      case (seq1, seq2) => seq1 ++ seq2
    })
}

def interleave[A](list: List[Stream[A]]): Stream[A] = combine(list).flatten
```